# GET Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fcb0e1de350

Tags: swift, server

I am trying to upload images to server. Images start uploading, after reaching 80%. I am getting this error:

> GET Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the
>   server." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fcb0e1de350

It also shows:

```
NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://apiurl/api/orders/372/images/6, 
NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://apiurl/api/orders/372/images/6,
```

What does it mean? Please help, I already spend 3 days to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. I worked with images's uploads, and have had much trouble, until i found a solution (somethings are in portuguese, but this isn't problem).

My code:

```
//
//  PostarViewController.swift
//  AppOnTheLine
//
//  Created by Elson Costa on 17/08/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Elson Costa. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

extension NSMutableData {

    func appendString(string: String) {
        let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
        appendData(data!)
    }
}

class PostarViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var btnSelecionar: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var imgPost: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var txtDescricao: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var lblEnviando: UILabel!

    var myActivityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        iniciarComponentes()
    }

    func iniciarComponentes(){
        myActivityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,50,50))
        myActivityIndicator.center = self.view.center
        myActivityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        myActivityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
        self.view.addSubview(myActivityIndicator)
    }

    @IBAction func selecionarImg(sender: AnyObject) {
        selectType(0)
    }

    @IBAction func tirarFoto(sender: AnyObject) {
        selectType(1)
    }

    func selectType(tipo:Int){
        let image = UIImagePickerController()
        image.delegate = self
        if tipo == 0 {
            image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        }else{
            image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        }
        image.allowsEditing = false
        self.presentViewController(image, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        imgPost.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: [String: String]?, filePathKey: String?, imageDataKey: NSData, boundary: String) -> NSData {
        let body = NSMutableData()

        if parameters != nil {
            for (key, value) in parameters! {
                body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
                body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
                body.appendString("\(value)\r\n")
            }
        }

        let filename = "myImage.jpg"
        let mimetype = "image/jpg"

        body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
        body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
        body.appendString("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
        body.appendData(imageDataKey)
        body.appendString("\r\n")

        body.appendString("--\(boundary)--\r\n")

        return body
    }

    @IBAction func enviarPost(sender: AnyObject) {
        activityInSwitch(true)

        if imgPost.image != nil && txtDescricao.text != "" {

            lblEnviando.hidden = false
            let urlWBS = NSURL(string:"myserver.com/salvar_post.php")! //HERE YOU PUT YOUR SERVER LINK!
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:urlWBS);
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

            let param = [
                "user"  : "\(usuario.getId())",
                "post"    : "\(txtDescricao.text!)"
            ]

            let boundary = "Boundary-\(NSUUID().UUIDString)"

            request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

            let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imgPost.image!, 1)
            if imageData == nil { return }

            request.HTTPBody = createBodyWithParameters(param, filePathKey: "file", imageDataKey: imageData!, boundary: boundary)

            let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in

                if(error != nil){
                    print("error = \(error!)")
                    self.lblEnviando.hidden = true
                    self.exibirAlert("Aconteceu um erro!", msg:"Por favor, tente novamente!", nameBtn:"Continuar")
                    return
                }

                do{
                    let myJSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                        let result = myJSON!["success"] as! String
                        if (result == "1"){

                            self.activityInSwitch(false)
                            self.txtDescricao.text = ""
                            self.imgPost.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder.png")
                            self.lblEnviando.hidden = true
                            self.exibirAlert("Post Enviado", msg:"Seu post foi enviado com sucesso!", nameBtn:"OK")

                        }else{

                            self.activityInSwitch(false)
                            self.lblEnviando.hidden = true
                            self.exibirAlert("Aconteceu um Erro", msg:"\(myJSON!["message"])", nameBtn:"Continuar")
                        }
                    })

                }catch{

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                        self.activityInSwitch(false)
                        self.lblEnviando.hidden = true
                        self.exibirAlert("Aconteceu um erro!", msg:"Por favor, tente novamente!", nameBtn:"Continuar")
                    })
                }
            }
            task.resume()

        }else{
            self.activityInSwitch(false)
            self.lblEnviando.hidden = true
            self.exibirAlert("Verificar Campos", msg:"Verifique os campos!", nameBtn:"Continuar")
        }
    }

    func activityInSwitch(ligar:Bool){
        if (ligar){
            self.myActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
        }else{
            self.myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
        }
    }

    func exibirAlert(titleAlert: String, msg: String, nameBtn:String){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: titleAlert, message: msg, preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: nameBtn, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Now, my php file **(salvar_post.php)**:

```
<?php
include_once("Conexao.php");

try{

    if(!$conectou){
        //nfpc: Não foi possível conectar
        throw new Exception("nfpc");
    }

    if (!isset($_POST['user']) && !isset($_POST['post']) && !isset($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
        //dnp: Dados não Preenchidos
        throw new Exception("dnp"); 
    }

    $user           = $_POST["user"];
    $text           = $_POST["post"];

    $data_hora_post = date('d/m/Y') . " às " . date('H:i:s');

    $nome_imagem    = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $ext            = strtolower(strrchr($nome_imagem, "."));
    $imageName      = "img_post_" . date('YmdHis') . $ext;

    $target_dir = "imagens";
    if(!file_exists($target_dir)){
        mkdir($target_dir, 0777);
    }
    $target_dir     = $target_dir . "/" . $imageName;

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_dir)){

        $resultQuery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tb_post(id_user, text_post, data_hora_post, image) VALUES ('{$user}', '{$text}', '{$data_hora_post}', '{$imageName}');");

        if ($resultQuery){

            $response["success"] = "1";
            $response["message"] = "O post foi salvo e imagem enviada com sucesso!";
            echo json_encode($response);

        }else{
            //Não foi possivel salvar o post
            throw new Exception("nfpsp");
        }

    }else{

        //Não salvou a imagem
        throw new Exception("nsai");

    }

}catch(Exception $ex){

    $response = array();

    switch ($ex->getMessage())
    {
        case 'nfpc':
            $response["success"] = "0";
            $response["message"] = "Não foi possivel conectar. ERROR: " . mysql_error();
            break;

        case 'dnp':
            $response["success"] = "0";
            $response["message"] = "Dados não preenchidos. ERROR: " . mysql_error();
            break;

        case 'nsai':
            $response["success"] = "0";
            $response["message"] = "Não foi possível salvar a imagem.";
            break;

        case 'nfpsp':
            $response["success"] = "0";
            $response["message"] = "Não foi possível salvar o post.";
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
}?>
```